# Showing certain map is continuous and linear.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X=C[0,1]$ with norm $$\|f\|_1=\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt$$ and $Y=C[0,1]$ with norm $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|$.
>
> Define $K: C[0,1]\times C[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ by $K(f)=\int_{0}^{1}K(s,t)f(t)dt,\ s\in [0,1]$. Show that $K$ is a continuous linear map.

The linearity follows from the the linearity of integral. But I don't have any clue to show that it is continuous. Any help?

Comment: It's a bit confusing because there seems to be two different maps called $K$. Also, as defined $K$ only takes "one" element of $C[0,1]$ rather than two of them

Comment: Your map, as defined, does not map $C[0,1]\times C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ but $C[0,1]$ to some function space. To inspect continuity you need to say which norm you use on the source and which on the target.

Comment: @user340297: I think it is a typo in the question. Let the inside be small $k$.

Comment: @Thomas: $\|\cdot\|_1$.

Comment: $\left| \int K(s,t)f(t)\,dt\right| \le \int |K(s,t)| \cdot |f(t)|\,dt \le ||f||_{\infty} \int |K(s,t)|\,dt$ - isn't this quite routine stuff?

Comment: @user340297 It certainly is, but as others pointed out the question is not well posted. For example  $K (s,t) $ is not in $C [0,1] $.

Comment: @MaikPickl True that, but then if it was a question about whether this question was well posed, I think OP should've mentioned that in the post. If that was a focus of the question he probably mentioned something about it rather than saying it is linear - while it is linear there's something very wrong in very definition of the map

Comment: @user340297 I actually think that OP is not aware that the problem is ill posed. And I think that is actually the main problem. The first step in solving a problem is understanding it. If he hasn't realized there is a problem in the formulation I would argue there is no chance for him understanding the solution.